# NullpointExcepction error in Bookmark Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, sharedpreferences

I'm getting that error when I execute my app. The aim is to add an activity to a list, and access that activity by pressing a button in the list.

I took the code from a tutorial, there are no errors in the activity code. I'm able to add to "favourites" my activity, which is listed in another activity. But when I try to enter that activity via button, it throws me NullPointException error.

Here is the code of the activity:

```
public class BookmarksActivity extends Activity {

private TextView mEmptyText;
private LinearLayout mBookmarkLayout;

private Context mContext;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.bookmarks);

    mContext = getApplicationContext();

    mEmptyText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.empty_textview);
    mBookmarkLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.bookmark_insert_point);

    getAllKeys();
}

private void getAllKeys()
{
    SharedPreferences sp = this.getSharedPreferences("bookmarks", MODE_PRIVATE);
    Map<String,?> keys = sp.getAll();

    int count = 0;
    for(Map.Entry<String,?> entry : keys.entrySet())
    {
        String value = entry.getValue().toString();
        System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!value = "+value);
        String delimiter = ",";
        String[] values_array = value.split(delimiter);
        addBookmark(values_array);
        count++; //keep track of the number of bookmarks
    }

    //if there are no bookmarks, display a text view saying so.  Otherwise, make the text view go away
    if (count == 0)
    {
        mEmptyText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mEmptyText.setText(getString(R.string.no_bookmarks));
    }
    else
        mEmptyText.setVisibility(View.GONE);

}

private void addBookmark(String[] values_array)
{       
    LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v = vi.inflate(R.layout.single_bookmark, null);

    TextView text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.bookmark_text);
    Button button = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.bookmark_button);

    text.setText(values_array[1]);

    final String myClass = values_array[0];
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Class<?> cl = null;
            try {
                cl = Class.forName(myClass);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(mContext, cl);
            startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    });

    // insert into main view
    mBookmarkLayout.addView(v, 0, new      LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,  LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
    System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!Just added a view");
}
}
```

I get the error at: Intent myIntent = new Intent(mContext, cl);

Maybe myClass is null, but I don't know hot to find out.

Thanks!

**EDIT: LogCat added**

```
09-23 20:04:53.367: E/AndroidRuntime(629): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-23 20:04:53.367: E/AndroidRuntime(629): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-23 20:04:53.367: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:76)
09-23 20:04:53.367: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:3301)
09-23 20:04:53.367: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at com.and.mememe.FavouritesActivity$1.onClick(FavouritesActivity.java:101)
09-23 20:04:53.367: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
09-23 20:04:53.367: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
09-23 20:04:53.367: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
09-23 20:04:53.367: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-23 20:04:53.367: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-23 20:04:53.367: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
09-23 20:04:53.367: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-23 20:04:53.367: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-23 20:04:53.367: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
09-23 20:04:53.367: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
09-23 20:04:53.367: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**EDIT 2**

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Class<?> cl = null;
            try {
                cl = Class.forName(myClass);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(mContext, cl);
            startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    });
```

Comment: First you aren't getting a `NPE` there...post your full logcat. Second, you don't need `Application Context` there, `Activity Context` will work. So this `mContext = getApplicationContext();` could be `mContext = this;` but there's no need for that either. Just use `v.getContext()`

Comment: @codeMagic Thank you for your answer. I've replaced it and used v.getContext() but the error persists.

Comment: Your problem is at line 101 of your `FavouritesActivity.java` in an `onClick()`. That's the code you need to post.

Comment: @codeMagic oops you're right! I've said line 102 instead. onClick code added in EDIT 2. Thanks

Comment: So exactly which line is 101? And that `onClick()` is from `FavouritesActivity.java` not `BookmarksActivity.java` as you have originally?

Comment: @codeMagic Sorry I had the tutorial activity called "BookmarkActivity" opened and I copied that code to mine. But it is copy-pasted, I have not changed anything, the error is in line 101 which is the onClick you've mentioned. Sorry about that

Comment: But I still don't know which line is 101!

Comment: Line 101 is the parenthesis at the end of:     e.printStackTrace();
            }

Comment: Then you need to rerun your project and get a new logcat because that can't cause a `NPE`, obviously. The logcat you show has something null at line 101 in FavouritesActivity and it can't be caused by a parenthesis

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61794/discussion-between-isaias-and-codemagic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here, ultimately, is that `myClass` isn't returning a valid class name. So there is no `Activity` to actually start.

This code here

```
try {
            cl = Class.forName(myClass);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

is catching a `ClassNotFoundException` but the code goes on to try and start the `Activity` which is invalid. To fix this, put the `Intent` code inside the `try` block. This way, when it catches the exception, something can be done with it such as logging, printing out a message, etc... But, most importantly, it won't try to start the invalid Activity. The `myClass` variable needs to be checked for validity. It has the wrong path or is misspelled.

```
try {
        cl = Class.forName(myClass);
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(mContext, cl);
        startActivity(myIntent);
     } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
```